# How do I find out why compact command appears to hang on certain files?

Tags: windows-server-2008, compression

After extending the hard disk sizes on a Windows 2008 server I am trying to revert the compressing of a lot of files on the hard drives. 
I use the command `compact /u /s /i /f /q` for it.
But it appears to hang on certain files (so I can skip the folder with the files it appears to hang on), so I have to do folder by folder instead of the whole drive in one go.
How to find out why it hangs on certain files?

Answer (score 0):

Due to NTFS Compression limitations I'd suggested to remove compression attribute from the folders first, then from the enclosed files. That is why the folder-by-folder approach works for you. Unfortunately, Explorer interface can't apply that change only to folders and subfolders without files but instead allows to "Apply changes to this folder, subfolders and files". As a workaround you could create a script that searches for subdirectories and removes compression attribute from subdirectories only. Then proceed with files.

Comment: I thinks the folder by folder works for me beacuse i can scip the problem folder/files.

Comment: Since NTFS compression can only work with the cluster size 4K or smaller, it could fail handling large files (tens of gigabytes). Are problem files on your server that large? It makes sense to check Event Log also.

Comment: The files are not large, certainly not gigabytes. I will check the event log.